# ASP.net MVC dependency injection with unity(DI container); how to inject dependency alias(specific types) based on the different controller types

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, dependency-injection, unity-container

I want to inject the specific dependencies using Unity OR any other DI container, based on the controller types.

Below is an example:

The 2 dependencies are of type interface `IAppLogger`:

```
1. NetworkLogger : IAppLogger
2. FileLogger : IAppLogger
```

Now below 2 controllers consume the dependency with abstraction IAppLogger.

```
1. NetworkController depends on IAppLogger
2. FileController depends on IAppLogger
```

In my MVC project I have installed Unity and Unity.mvc3 packages. After that I got a bootstrap.cs file where I can register the types. Now how should I set the DependencyResolver to resolve

```
IAppLogger to NetworkLogger for controller NetworkController
```

AND

```
IAppLogger to FileLogger for controller FileController.
```

**Edit:**

---

If things are dynamic with App then chaning the dependency types inside each controller would be hard as against doing it in service locator or resolver and have less footprint. In standalone app I can do it using alias while registering types.

```
Container.RegisterType<IAppLogger, NetworkLogger>("Network"); 
Container.RegisterType<IAppLogger, FileLogger >("File"); 

IAppLogger flogger = Container.Resolve<IAppLogger>("File");     
IAppLogger nlogger = Container.Resolve<IAppLogger>("Network");
```

Answer (score 1):

If `NetworkController` should always operate with a `NetworkLogger` then it should depend on `NetworkLogger`, not on `IAppLogger`. Or maybe on `INetworkLogger` if you want.

The same goes for `FileController`.

Comment: The idea is to provide higher level of abstraction and more control on service locator side of module. If things are dynamic with App then chaning the dependency types inside each controller would be hard as against doing it in service locator or resolver and have less footprint. In standalone app I can do it using alias while registering types.

`Container.RegisterType<IAppLogger, NetworkLogger>("Network")';
Container.RegisterType<IAppLogger, FileLogger >("File");


IAppLogger flogger = Container.Resolve<IAppLogger>("File");
'IAppLogger nlogger = Container.Resolve<IAppLogger>("Network");`

Comment: Another thing that comes to mind is `IAppLogger` should have 2 methods `LogToFile(string msg);` and `LogToNetwork(string msg);` Then the appropriate controller will call the method either to log into the file or over the network. This would break the abstraction from the controller about how the messages are logged. But the major concern in this case is for each controller I have to instantiate `IAppLogger` with File logger as well as Network logger and the dependency becomes heavy.